# Distribution of Sample Total - Explanation Please?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have the following question here, which is to do with the Normal distribution and probability:

> A ski-lift is designed with a load limit of 18,000lbs and claims a capacity of 100 people. If the weight of people using the lift is Normally distributed with mean 175lbs and standard deviation 30lbs, what is the probability that a group of 100 randomly selected people will exceed the load limit of the lift? Would you bewilling to use the lift?

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II03s.png)

**Could someone please explain this solution to me, including the values in the equation? Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to remember a property of Gaussian distribution:

*"Sum of independent gaussians is still gaussian with mean the sum of the single means and variance the sum of the individual variances"*.

[This can be easily proved using MGF].

Your individual distribution is $N(175;30^2)$ thus the distribution of the weight of the 100 guys is still a gaussian:

$$X\sim N[175\times100;30^2\times100]$$

Now  you can find the probability $P(Y>18000)$ simply standardizing ($Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$) and reading the result on the Z-tables

$$P(X>18000)=P(Z>\frac{18000-17500}{30\times10})=P(Z>1.67)=1-\Phi(1.67)= 4.75\%$$

---

The value $\Phi(1.67)= 0.9525$ is taken from Z-tables:

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks – that makes more sense. But one more thing regarding the question… Did you do the square root of a 100 because the question says: “what is the probability that a group of 100”, or did you do the square root of a 100 because of: “claims a capacity of 100”?

Comment: @shrewd.jude : the variance is  $\underbrace{30^2+30^2+30^2+...+30^2}_{100\text{ times}}=30^2\times 100$ so the standard deviation is $30\times 10$